# PyCharm IDE doesn't highlight undeclared variables

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I am using pyCharm 2018.1 community edition, is there a way for pyCharm to detect when I accidentally used a variable that does not exist ? I get other inspection highlighting but just not unresolved reference and it is really annoying when I find these small mistakes during compile time.

for example

print(doesnotexist) will not be highlighted in pycharm

I have enabled inspections and left defaults as is. 
is this normal ?

[image] 
 [image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot. PyCharm has such inspection and it is called `Unresolved references`. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/resolving-references.html

Comment: @user82383 Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Check your .idea folder and see if the inspection folder has been recently changed. I had to delete and let Pycharm recreate my profile.

[image]